# Method execution depends of response of an async method

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

My english is not the best, so I apologize in advance for that.

My situation is the following, I am developing an Android app and I have an async task, and in the **doInBackground** method have the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        getFirebaseUserChannels(new ResultListener<List<Channel>>() {
            @Override
            public void finish(List<Channel> firebaseUserChannels) {
                if (firebaseUserChannels.isEmpty()) {

                    getFirebaseChannels(new ResultListener<List<Canal>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void finish(List<Channel> firebaseChannels) {
                            saveChannelsSQLDatabase(firebaseChannels);
                            saveChannelsFirebaseDatabase(firebaseChannels);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    saveChannelsSQLDatabase(canalesUsuarioFB);
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

So, the method "***getFirebaseUserChannels***" is an async method that in response throws a *list*, and when that list is ready to use it, I have to evaluate it and use it.
But as you know, java executes the async method and continues until the ***return***.

I want that the "doInBackground" does not continue the execution until all the async methods executions ends.

So, How Could I do that? How is the best way to manage this situation?

Answer (score 0):

> How is the best way to manage this situation?

Get rid of the `AsyncTask` entirely. Have whatever code was going to execute the `AsyncTask` simply call `getFirebaseUserChannels()`.